# the union of two queries

Tags: php, sql

Help to merge the two sql query (TECDOC).

1. Display the name and part number;
2. Display the details of technical parameters.

How to combine these two queries?

```
SELECT
    ART_ARTICLE_NR,
    SUP_BRAND,
    DES_TEXTS.TEX_TEXT AS ART_COMPLETE_DES_TEXT,
    DES_TEXTS2.TEX_TEXT AS ART_STATUS_TEXT
FROM ARTICLES
    INNER JOIN DESIGNATIONS ON DESIGNATIONS.DES_ID = ART_COMPLETE_DES_ID
    INNER JOIN DES_TEXTS ON DES_TEXTS.TEX_ID = DESIGNATIONS.DES_TEX_ID
    INNER JOIN SUPPLIERS ON SUP_ID = ART_SUP_ID
    INNER JOIN ART_COUNTRY_SPECIFICS ON ACS_ART_ID = ART_ID
    INNER JOIN DESIGNATIONS 
        AS DESIGNATIONS2 ON DESIGNATIONS2.DES_ID = ACS_KV_STATUS_DES_ID
    INNER JOIN DES_TEXTS
        AS DES_TEXTS2 ON DES_TEXTS2.TEX_ID = DESIGNATIONS2.DES_TEX_ID
WHERE
    ART_ID IN ( 
                52277
        ) AND
    DESIGNATIONS.DES_LNG_ID = 19 AND
    DESIGNATIONS2.DES_LNG_ID = 19;
```

---

```
SELECT
    DES_TEXTS.TEX_TEXT AS CRITERIA_DES_TEXT,
    IFNULL(DES_TEXTS2.TEX_TEXT, ACR_VALUE) AS CRITERIA_VALUE_TEXT
FROM
    ARTICLE_CRITERIA
    LEFT JOIN DESIGNATIONS
        AS DESIGNATIONS2 ON DESIGNATIONS2.DES_ID = ACR_KV_DES_ID
    LEFT JOIN DES_TEXTS
        AS DES_TEXTS2 ON DES_TEXTS2.TEX_ID = DESIGNATIONS2.DES_TEX_ID
    LEFT JOIN CRITERIA ON CRI_ID = ACR_CRI_ID
    LEFT JOIN DESIGNATIONS ON DESIGNATIONS.DES_ID = CRI_DES_ID
    LEFT JOIN DES_TEXTS ON DES_TEXTS.TEX_ID = DESIGNATIONS.DES_TEX_ID
WHERE
    ACR_ART_ID IN (
            52277
        ) AND
    (DESIGNATIONS.DES_LNG_ID IS NULL OR DESIGNATIONS.DES_LNG_ID = 19) AND
        (DESIGNATIONS2.DES_LNG_ID IS NULL OR DESIGNATIONS2.DES_LNG_ID = 19);
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS articles ( ART_ID int(11) NOT NULL, ART_ARTICLE_NR varchar(66) NOT NULL, ART_SUP_ID smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL, ART_DES_ID int(11) DEFAULT NULL, ART_COMPLETE_DES_ID int(11) DEFAULT NULL, ART_PACK_SELFSERVICE smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL, ART_MATERIAL_MARK smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL, ART_REPLACEMENT smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL, ART_ACCESSORY smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL, ART_BATCH_SIZE1 int(11) DEFAULT NULL, ART_BATCH_SIZE2 int(11) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ART_ID), KEY ART_ARTICLE_NR (ART_ARTICLE_NR(10)) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS article_criteria ( ACR_ART_ID int(11) NOT NULL, ACR_GA_ID int(11) NOT NULL, ACR_SORT smallint(6) NOT NULL, ACR_CRI_ID smallint(6) NOT NULL, ACR_VALUE varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL, ACR_KV_DES_ID int(11) DEFAULT NULL, ACR_DISPLAY smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ACR_ART_ID,ACR_GA_ID,ACR_SORT) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS art_country_specifics ( ACS_ART_ID int(11) NOT NULL, ACS_PACK_UNIT int(11) DEFAULT NULL, ACS_QUANTITY_PER_UNIT int(11) DEFAULT NULL, ACS_KV_STATUS_DES_ID int(11) DEFAULT NULL, ACS_KV_STATUS varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL, ACS_STATUS_DATE datetime DEFAULT NULL, KEY ACS_ART_ID (ACS_ART_ID) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS criteria ( CRI_ID smallint(6) NOT NULL, CRI_DES_ID int(11) NOT NULL, CRI_SHORT_DES_ID int(11) DEFAULT NULL, CRI_UNIT_DES_ID int(11) DEFAULT NULL, CRI_TYPE binary(1) NOT NULL, CRI_KT_ID smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL, CRI_IS_INTERVAL smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL, CRI_SUCCESSOR smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (CRI_ID) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS designations ( DES_ID int(11) NOT NULL, DES_LNG_ID smallint(6) NOT NULL, DES_TEX_ID int(11) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (DES_ID,DES_LNG_ID) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS des_texts ( TEX_ID int(11) NOT NULL, TEX_TEXT text, PRIMARY KEY (TEX_ID) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS suppliers ( SUP_ID smallint(6) NOT NULL, SUP_BRAND varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL, SUP_SUPPLIER_NR smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL, SUP_COU_ID smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL, SUP_IS_HESS smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (SUP_ID) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Can you not combine them in your presentation layer?

Comment: IMHO most people would prefer reading lowercase with shorter correlation names. I think the queries could be merged, but I am too lazy to decypher them.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?  With PHP I'm assuming mySQL, but I sorta hope not (because CTEs would be useful here...).  Although, you probably want a view wrapping `Designations` and `Des_Texts` regardless.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this might work.  Please note that this is **not** tested (especially as you've neglected to provide us with the layout of your tables), and I've had to make guesses as to how `articles` is supposed to be correlated to `article_criteria`.

```
SELECT Articles.art_article_nr, Suppliers.sup_brand
       Article_Designations.text, Country_Specific_Designations.text,
       Article_Criteria_Designations.value,
       Article_Criteria_Designations.text
FROM Articles
JOIN (SELECT Designations.des_id, Des_Texts.tex_text as text
      FROM Designations
      JOIN Des_Texts
      ON Des_Texts.tex_id = Designations.des_tex_id
      AND Designations.des_lng_id = 19) as Article_Designations
ON Article_Designations.des_id = Articles.art_complete_des_id

JOIN Suppliers
ON Suppliers.sup_id = Articles.art_sup_id

JOIN Art_Country_Specific
ON Art_Country_Specific.acs_art_id = Articles.art_id
JOIN (SELECT Designations.des_id, Des_Texts.tex_text as text
      FROM Designations
      JOIN Des_Texts
      ON Des_Texts.tex_id = Designations.des_tex_id
      AND Designations.des_lng_id = 19) as Country_Specific_Designations
ON Country_Specific_Designations.des_id = Art_Country_Specific.acs_kv_status_des_id

LEFT JOIN (SELECT Article_Criteria.acr_art_id,
           COALESCE(Art_Cri_Designations.text, Article_Criteria.acr_value) as value,
           Criteria_Designations.text
           FROM Article_Criteria
           LEFT JOIN (SELECT Designations.des_id, Des_Texts.tex_text as text
                      FROM Designations
                      JOIN Des_Texts
                      ON Des_Texts.tex_id = Designations.des_tex_id
                      AND Designations.des_lng_id = 19) as Art_Cri_Designations
           ON Art_Cri_Designations.des_id = Article_Criteria.acr_kv_des_id
           LEFT JOIN (SELECT Criteria.cri_id, Des_Texts.tex_text as text
                      FROM Criteria
                      JOIN Designations
                      ON Designations.des_id = Criteria.cri_des_id
                      JOIN Des_Texts
                      ON Des_Texts.tex_id = Designations.des_tex_id
                      AND Designations.des_lng_id = 19) as Criteria_Designations
           ON Criteria_Designations.cri_id = Article_Criteria.acr_cri_id
           ) as Article_Criteria_Designations
ON Article_Criteria_Designations.acr_art_id = Articles.art_id

WHERE Articles.art_id IN (52277)
```